# Get single result from multiple-context function call without intermediary variable

Tags: go

In [Go](http://golang.org) I can use the [underscore](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Blank_identifier) to ignore a return value from a function that returns multiple values. For instance:

```
res, _ := strconv.Atoi("64")
```

Suppose I wanted to use the first value directly into another function call (while ignoring error checking best practices, in this example):

```
myArray := make([]int, strconv.Atoi("64"))
```

The compiler will complain that I'm using a multiple-value function in a singe-value context:

```
./array-test.go:11: multiple-value strconv.Atoi() in single-value context
```

Is it possible to "pick and choose" from the return values in a single-line without resorting to [auxiliary functions](http://ernestmicklei.com/2013/11/from-multiple-to-single-value-context-in-go/)?

Answer (score 1):

The only real way to do it is to create some utility "bypass" function, and since this is Go, you'll have to declare one per type.

for example:

```
func noerrInt(i int, e err) int {
   return i
}
```

then you can do:

```
myArray := make([]int, noerrInt(strconv.Atoi("64")))
```

But really, this pretty much sucks, AND ignores best practices.